# Using jQuery, I am submitting a form wihout refreshing the browser and I need help in listing the submitted data in a custom table column

Tags: php, jquery

I have a table where it's rows are generated by a foreach loop.

Each table row has two columns, one with a form and the other with the forms submitted data, which I have called notes. (and updates using a jQuery library without refreshing the browser).

```
<script>
    $(".notes_column").each(function(){

            var $myform = $(this).find('.notes_form');
            var $mynotes = $(this).find('.notes');

            $myform.validate({
                submitHandler: function(form) {
                    $.post('process.php', $myform.serialize(), function(data) {
                        $mynotes.html(data);
                    });
                }
            });


    }); // each function
</script>


<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter" border="1" cellpadding="5">
<thead> 
    <tr>
        <th>Notes</th>
        <th>Submit Note</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
    foreach($myarray as $myvar){
        echo ' 
            <tr>
                <td>ID LIKE TO PLACE THE content of the div class="notes"  HERE, HOW CAN I DO IT?</td>
                <td class="notes_column">
                    <form class="notes_form" action="" method="post">
                        <input class="q" type="text" name="notes" size="30" placeholder="Place your notes here..." />
                        <input class="searchsubmit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
                    </form>
                    <div class="notes"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        ';
    }
?>
</tbody> 
</table>
```

Right now I use a jQuery **each function** which iterates through each table column, and for each column with the class name **".notes_column"** populates a div with the **class "notes"** with the submitted data.

**The question is listed inside the code with capitalized letters**, **how can I populate the other column with the forms submitted data?**

Any ideas?

Ty

Comment: Why aren't you retrieving all the data with PHP _before_ the page is loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I would create a <div> in the first <td> such as

<td>
    <div class="put_notes_here">ID LIKE TO PLACE THE content of the div class="notes"  HERE, HOW CAN I DO IT?</div>
</td>

Then populate it the same as you did before
$mynotes.closest("tr").find(".put_notes_here").html(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the selector for your each to $('#myTable tr'), then you can iterate through each  in your table.

Then you could either do an each on the tr object to access each td, or make use of jQuery's :first-child and nth-child(2) etc in a subsequent selector